# cqlsh -e "copy table" hangs forever

Tags: cassandra

I have a handful of tables that I want to copy from one Cassandra cluster to another; I figured the most straightforward way to do this would be to run a series of shell commands like:

cqlsh  -e "copy keyspace.table1 to 'table1.csv' with header = true;

(and then a series of inverse shell commands to copy into the new cluster).

However, when I run this, I see:

Using 11 child processes

Starting copy of keyspace.table1 with columns [column1, column2, column3, column4].

But the process hangs forever, never adding to the target CSV file.

Comment: We face similar issue with cqlsh.py script, we are using -f option to input cql file. Just curious, if you figured out possible cause and solution

Answer (score 1):

What is # of rows and size of each row in the table you are trying to copy? Its not optimal to use COPY if both size of a row and # of rows are huge.

One option you can try out is to reduce batch size.

```
cqlsh -e "copy table keyspace.table1 to 'table1.csv' with header = true AND MAXBATCHSIZE=5;
```

This may take longer, but it will surely end. I have had similar issue with a table having close to 30M records and reducing batch size helped.

Comment: > What is # of rows and size of each row in the table you are trying to copy?

Well, one table is just 35,547 rows - if I run the copy command from cqlsh (without the "-e"), it only takes 6 seconds to copy all 5M of table data, but if I run the exact same command with "-e" (or if I use -f to pass in a series of commands) it just hangs.  I tried it with the maxbatchsize and I see the same behavior... it must just be an oddity on my end if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

It may be more efficient to use take a snapshot of the table with

`nodetool snapshot  -cf <table_name> -t <snpashot_id> <keyspace>`

where keyspace and table name are the names of your structure; snapshot_id will be a label that will help you to identify the snapshot.

You will be abele to verify the snapshot with `nodetool listsnapshots`, then restore it with the procedure explained [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/operations/opsBackupSnapshotRestore.html).

Once that you are done with the procedure, you'll need to do some house cleaning with `nodetool clearsnapshot <snapshot_id>`

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that.  Still would like to know why the cqlsh hangs, but maybe it doesn't matter.